# How to properly setup localhost for react + api development

Tags: reactjs, api

I am **developing** app with **react**-redux. And I am using the quick development, which always build my client at **localhost:3000**

I have my **api written in php**, and its on **localhost:80**.

So its **cross-origin, but on production its not**. So I would like to develop it while being on the same domain+port. But I have no clue how to set it up.

I am using MAMP - Apache for the php and yarn (create-react-app) for react.

> So it can't run at the same port.
>
> Anyone any ideas how to solve this problem?

When I use "yarn start" I can edit my react code and its compiled upon save and I can see the edited code within seconds at the localhost:3000

Is it possible to "deploy" it in this "developer" mode into some folder, where I could possibly setup a server using actually MAMP ( apache ) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if for client side of your application you have use `create-react-app`, you can add a proxy configuration in package.json file.

```
"proxy": {
    "/apiRoute": {
      "target": "http://localhost:80"
    },
  },
```

So all your request will be redirected to port 80(PHP) from client side.

The /apiRoute is the name of the routes `(GET, POST, PUT..)` you had defined in PHP. So i would suggest to make a pattern in PHP for all routes like /api/**, so in package.json instead of adding all routes, you can something like below

```
"proxy": {
  "/api/*": {
     "target": "http://localhost:80"
   },
 },
```